# Ruby on Rails duvida

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where

Tenho esse def no models, verifiquei com pry e tem valores chegando normalmente, no entando eles nao salvam na variavel @inventory e abaixo coloquei a class Inventory tambem, queria saber se alguem poderia dar uma ajuda, desde jah agradeço.

MODEL TRADE

```
        def survivor_owns_items(survivor, trade_items)
        trade_items.each do |trade_item|
            binding.pry 
            @inventory = Inventory.includes(:Survivor,:Item).where({Survivor: survivor, Item: trade_items})
            if @inventory.quantity < trade_items.quantity
                return false
            end
        end
```

CLASSE INVENTORY

```
           class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
             belongs_to :survivor
             belongs_to :item
            validates :survivor, :item, presence: true
            validates :survivor, uniqueness: { scope: :item }
          end
```

JSON:

```
     {
     "trade": {
        "survivor_one_id": "1",        
         "survivor_two_id": "2",
         "survivor_two_items": [{"name": "Water", "quantity":"1"}],                       
         "survivor_one_items": [{"name":"Medication","quantity":"2"}]
        }
     }
```

Comment: não deveria ser `@inventory = Inventory.includes(:Survivor,:Item).where({Survivor: survivor, Item: trade_item})`, sem o 's'?

Comment: enquanto `@inventory.quantity < trade_items.quantity` for `false`, ele sobrescreve `@inventory`, essa é a intenção?

Comment: A intençao da comparação é verificar se eu tenho quantidade suficiente do item que eu vou futuramente fazer uma troca com outro player, caso nao tenha ele retorna false somente,fiz a alteraçao proposta, esse com certeza era um erro, porem o principal ainda nao foi corrigido, quando executado verificado com o pry o que eu tenho na no @inventory ele retorna:
inventory
=> []

Comment: para cada `trade_item` em `trade_items`, o código após `binding_pry` retorna um `array`? (estou tentando entender o motivo da comparação dentro da iteração)

Comment: Sim, esqueci de mencionar que é api rest, então o seguinte JSON é passado(adicionei ali em cima), sim pode ter mais itens entao eu percorro o meus itens comparando eles.

Comment: boa - melhor editar e incluir essas informações na sua pergunta; sugiro também que você separe em blocos de código para não parecer que está tudo no mesmo arquivo ou em sequência como aparece na pergunta

Comment: Outra coisa, posso retirar no momento essa comparaçao ali dentro, so precisava que a atribuição com os dados do survivor e dos items fossem para dentro do  @inventory porem isso nao acontece.